# How to prove that this expression is equivalent to the squeeze operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm taking an MIT OpenCourseWare talking about the squeezed state:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NXgobnaBN7U&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60QlYNsy52fctVBOlk-4lYx&index=15

At 1:14:12 Prof. Zwiebach claimed $\frac{1}{\sqrt{cosh\gamma}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}tanh\gamma\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}^{\dagger}}|0\rangle = e^{-\frac{\gamma}{2}(\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}^{\dagger}-\hat{a}\hat{a})}|0\rangle$, but didn't give the proof. How can I prove this equation?

I also find a related post: [Deriving Squeezing and Higher Order Squeezing operators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/412669/deriving-squeezing-and-higher-order-squeezing-operators) telling the squeeze operator cannot be 'derived' in any meaningful sense but is a definition. I don't understand if the above equation can be rigorously derived, then we can say we derived the squeeze operator right?

Comment: what is $\gamma$?

Comment: @user2723984 $\gamma$ is defined to be $e^{\gamma}=\sqrt{\frac{m_1w_1}{m_2w_2}}$, where $m_1,w_1$ and $m_2w_2$ are the mass and frequencies for the harmonic oscillator at different Hamiltonian $H_1$ and $H_2$.

Comment: I've honestly never seen the first form. I don't think it's a straightforward derivation. You can take a look at the following articles: D. R. Truax, Phys. Rev. D. 31 (1985) 1988, R. A. Fisher, M. M. Nieto, and V. D. Sandberg, Phys. Rev. D. 29 (1984) 1107, R. Gilmore, J. Math. Phys. 15, 2090 (1974). They seem to address the subject. These days I don't have the time to do the calculation or to check them, but now I'm curious about this derivation!

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll check these.

Comment: @y ing Actually the answer you are searching for is in the article by Fisher et al. (1984), section III, I just checked it. It's a nice derivation and it is **not** straightforward :)